# Android Timezone get default returning wrong value

Tags: java, android, kotlin, time, timezone

i have an application. I want to get phone's time as long value. Although the phone's timezone is UTC+3, UTC 0 is displayed in all the following operations. I think app locale is wrong.

Phone Time is : 10.46

`TimeZone.getDefault().id // return UTC`

`Date() // Wed Sep 14 07:46:57 UTC 2022`

`LocalDateTime().now() // 2022-09-14T07:46:22.849`

`Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) // 2022-09-14 07:50:18.153`

How can I get right timezone?

Comment: What about `ZonedDateTime.now()` or `OffsetDateTime.now()`? What do they show?

Comment: `ZonedDateTime.now()` is  2022-09-14T08:03:17.441Z[UTC]
`OffsetDateTime.now()` is 2022-09-14T08:04:17.712Z

Comment: If you want the *phone's time as long value* , does that mean you want the epoch seconds or millis?

Comment: What does `ZoneId.systemDefault()` return? Is it UTC?

Comment: `ZoneId.systemDefault()` is UTC. Yes, I want to millis

Comment: Millis are independent from any zone or offset, so simply do `long millis = Instant.now().toEpochMilli()` (in Java).

Answer (score 2):

If you want the current millis, simply use an `Instant`, get the current moment by using `Instant.now()` and receive the value in milliseconds via `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()`. You can use that value in order to display date and time depending on a `ZoneId` or `ZoneOffset`, which may be the `systemDefault()` or any given one.

Here's an example in Java:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get the current moment
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    // and print its epoch millis
    System.out.println("Current millis: " + now.toEpochMilli());
    // then create two different time zones (ZoneId in java.time)
    ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC");
    ZoneId ankara = ZoneId.of("Europe/Istanbul");
    // then create different (!) datetimes using the same instant but different zones
    ZonedDateTime utcZdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now, utc);
    ZonedDateTime ankaraZdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now, ankara);
    // print them
    System.out.println(utcZdt);
    System.out.println(ankaraZdt);
}
```

Output (about a minute ago):

```
Current millis: 1663143809106
2022-09-14T08:23:29.106785Z[UTC]
2022-09-14T11:23:29.106785+03:00[Europe/Istanbul]
```

The millis (resp. `Instant`s) are independent from any zone or offset and you can use them to display **different datetimes based on the same `Instant`**.

Comment: In this case only works Ankara or another place. The application must be able to work anywhere in the world. I can't get timezone value("Europe/Istanbul, Europe/London etc"). In have a countdown timer. It's only working in UTC-0 timezone.

Comment: Well, use the `ZoneId.systemDefault()` if you want it as flexible as possible. Note that the zone of the JVM/device may have been changed/manipulated by users. I wouldn't expect any specific zone for a device, how can you tell that it's *wrong*? Why do you expect UTC+3 on a device with UTC? Is there any clock displayed that shows the expected time? If yes, check if that clock app uses a defined value… May be a UTC+3-clock or any option was set to UTC.

Comment: The time of the phone is UTC+3 but when I run these codes, the value I get is UTC-0. (`ZoneId.systemDefault()`, `OffsetDateTime.now()`,  `TimeZone.getDefault()`, `Date()`, `LocalDateTime().now()`, `Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())`)

Comment: Then the time is not corresponding to the system default. In that case, you cannot rely on it, I think. You will need a workaround. How do you know the time is UTC+3? Where in the phone do you see that time?

Comment: When I enter the phone's settings, I see that it is UTC +3.

Comment: Ok, that‘s weird. What phone is it and what happens if you switch to UTC and execute the code again?

Comment: the result is still UTC :(

Comment: So the time obviously doesn't depend on that very setting… Does the code work as expected with a different phone (if you have one)?

Comment: no i tried it on different phones it doesn't work right for this app. I tried creating a new app and it worked. I couldn't find any difference between these two apps.